# Error in kafka consumer with spring boot (disconnected)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am getting this error in consumer when using spring boot:

```
2021-10-11 19:42:41.388  WARN 64415 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-something-1, groupId=some_group_id] Bootstrap broker my_address:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

My application.properties are:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers = my_address:9093
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id= some_group_id
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset = earliest
```

Java code will call following properties in consumer.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=my_address:9093
schema.registry.url=https://URL.net
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=some_path.jks
ssl.truststore.password=pinPass
ssl.keystore.location=some_path.jks
ssl.keystore.password=pinPass
ssl.key.password=pinPass
```

in java:

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
```

Please let me know if any more inputs needed.

Note: same code works fine for localhost..Also there is no issue with server as i have another code without spring and it works fine!

Comment: What are the `advertised.listeners` / `listeners` settings of your remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Your "security.protocol=SSL" means you will use SSL for identity authentication, please check your SSL Keys and Certificates, otherwise using "security.protocol=PLAINTEXT" will use the default, Un-authenticated, non-encrypted channel.

refer to:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html

Comment: Yes, security protocol needed to be SSL. Certificates are fine, as consumer works in core java code and from command line, but not with spring code!

Comment: I still recommend that you try to determine the scope of the problem. In addition, you can check the advertised.listeners/listeners settings of Kafka Bootstrap Servers (which may cause the cluster address error) and the server firewall settings.

Comment: I will try to get those settings, however as mentioned, I have another code without spring boot and it connects to the server just fine. Thus I wanted to check why is it not working with spring. Anything more to add in application.properties?